# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in VS 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with SQL Server 2008R2 and VS 2010

I kept getting this error when I browse I tried opening every page but the same error pops up.
Please explain briefly and in simple word what should I do I'm new to this.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

> MyProject.login1.ImageButton3_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in C:\Users\prakash\Desktop\MyProject R2\MyProject R2\MyProject\login1.aspx.cs:26
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +115
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +124
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

**Source Code**

```
protected void ImageButton3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopingConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
        string s = "select * from login";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlDataReader dtr;
            dtr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                if (dtr[0].ToString().Equals(TextBox1.Text) && dtr[1].ToString().Equals(TextBox2.Text))
                {


                    Response.Cookies["uname"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
                    Response.Cookies["pwd"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
                    Response.Cookies["role"].Value = dtr[2].ToString();
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBox1.Text, false);

                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "your credential are incorrect";
                }
```

Comment: can you post your code.?

Comment: That error gives you the line of code and the file. Please post it.

Comment: prakash, show some code of login1.aspx.cs

Comment: Code of Masterpage or the any other page?

Comment: Where you are getting error, post that page code..!

Comment: to be more specific post the code that deals with imagebutton, what value you are passing with image buttong

Comment: post your code behind file not the design page

Comment: prakash, post the login1.aspx.cs code... you have posted login1.aspx code

Comment: post the button click even code of the **ImageButton3**

Comment: not the design code..!! Please post your backend coding for this.. To make it clear double click on the ImageButton3 you will be taken the code file, post that code here..!

Comment: Sorry for posting the wrong code now I posted the right one. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Gosh. That is horrible! You are bringing back the entire table and looping through it to check the username and password. No hashing of passwords. No separation of concerns.

Comment: Keep a break point and by pressing <kbd> F11 </kbd> check the exact line where you're getting error.!

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian
I didn't get your point? What do I do?

Comment: Keep a breakpoint in the line protected void ImageButton3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) and press F11 and by pressing it again again you will see the line where you get error.!

Comment: When I tried to Debug this time the following error shows up in Source Error. Error is on LINE 6

Line 4:  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
Line 5:      User Name<br />
Line 6:      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
Line 7:  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
Line 8:      ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="fill usename "></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: do you have TextBox1_TextChanged code in your file?? double click in textbox1 and check with that

Comment: Yes I do have the code in my file. And there's no error in that. Plus this error is showing in every page of my project. Whichever page I browse same error pops up.

Comment: Try commenting out those lines and run..!! I am unable to reproduce the error. as it is too broad and very hard to find it

Comment: Can you please help me through TeamViewer Sir please? I have to submit this project tomorrow and It's 300 marks project. please.

Comment: Did you read the duplicate? Instead of waiting for one of us to give you the fish you could have caught it yourself by now.

Comment: What is the text in line 26? ..Login1.aspx.cs:26 ...

Comment: @MartinSmith

I did read duplicates before posting it here. I have been doing this from last night. I'm a beginner to coding that's why I'm having so much trouble. I'm sorry.

Comment: I agree.. The Null Reference question gives a general solution, this is a question on a specific solution. This is not duplicate. So what's on line 26?

Comment: Line 6: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>


And it was on Line 6 not Line 26

Comment: no: the error is still this "MyProject.login1.ImageButton3_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in C:\Users\prakash\Desktop\MyProject R2\MyProject R2\MyProject\login1.aspx.cs:26 " here it's saying that error is in login1.aspx.cs not in login1.aspx, line 26

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopingConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

This was on Line26

Comment: So does your web.config file contain a connection string called `shopingConnectionString1`?

Comment: @EmanueleGreco - The point of supplying a canonical question answer pair is because StackOverflow is not about supplying highly localised personalised debugging sessions of no value to future visitors.

Comment: Yeah it does contain.

Comment: Definitely the same? It says "shoping" and not "shopping"?

Comment: Yeah it says the same.

Comment: so type in line 25 (before line 26) this code ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopingConnectionString1"] and debug it. Is this null or not?

Comment: then in Immediate window get ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopingConnectionString1"].ConnectionString and post it here